# Backing up and restoring a Jenkins Docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have an issue backing up a Jenkins Docker container.

So far I've tried:

- Backing up the JENKINS_HOME directory: which doesn't work because the tar.gz ends up being corrupt. In cases where it does work, even with privileged as an option inside the new container i cannot extract the tar.gz of JENKINS_HOME anywhere.
- Exporting the container and importing it on a new machine: which doesn't work because every import results in `touch: cannot touch '': No such file or directory` and `Can not write to . Wrong volume permissions?` errors.
- Also tried to use thinBackup, but for some reason it doesn't have write access to the backup directory.
- I found the following [instructions](https://medium.com/pacroy/how-to-backup-and-restore-your-jenkins-data-volume-in-docker-2ac66d99315a) but upon reaching the following:

  ```
  docker run --rm --volumes-from <container> -v <local_path>:<container_path> ubuntu tar cvf <container_path>/jenkins_home.tar /var/jenkins_home
  ```

  I get the following error:

  ```
  tar: /backup/jenkins_home.tar: Cannot open: Permission denied
  tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
  ```

How would I go about to backing this container and its plugins/builds/projects?

Comment: Mount and attach a docker volume to the host volume, keep all stateful stuff (configuration files etc) on the host volume.

Comment: I believe jenkins containers have volumes attached by default.